# Azure/ PowershellL How to echo a value from a parameter containing a name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am writing a pipeline where the parameter is passed down containing a key name (for example). Within the PowerShell commands, I retrieve the key and would like to display the value to the user who deploys this pipeline. The key is an environment variable name.

```
parameters:
  key: ''

steps:
  - powershell: |
      echo "The value is: $(${{ parameters.key }})"
```

And, I get this error:

- echo "The value is: $(MySilverKey)"

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MySilverKey:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

However, it works if I hardcoded the key in the echo string like below:

echo "The value is: $(MySilverKey)"

The console displays:
The value is: Silver

Answer (score 0):

To use an environment variable within PowerShell, you can prefix the variable name with `$env:`. Could you please check if the below sample script helps ?

```
$key = $env:{{ parameters.key }}
      echo "The value is: $key"
```

I hope you are ensuring that your environment variable is set before running your pipeline. You could set it using `Set-Item` cmdlet in PowerShell or through `environment variables` section in pipeline settings.